# Manual file-upload dissapeared from phpstorm, howto recover?

Tags: php, upload, phpstorm

I am using **phpstorm 7.0** for development and was used to upload files via right-mouse button and then choose {upload}.

My newest project runs on Symfony and Doctrine so I had to configure some things in phpstorm for that.

But now, the manual upload function is gone and I am unable to find a way to get it back. This was very handy for minor changes that had to be uploaded fast for testing.

I have searched Google and went through every setting-option in phpstorm but I cannot find the way to restore the manual upload setting.

I hope I made my problem clear..

Comment: `Settings | Deployment` -- all should be there. If that settings page is not available then make sure that "Remote Hosts Access" plugin is enabled.

Comment: Have you read http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#manually ?

Comment: Moreover, you should make sure that you have your remote host set as Default, for 1-click Uploading, rather than having to choose which server

Comment: @LazyOne: That page is available and I can test the connection but I cannot configure the manual {upload-to} option.

Comment: @Noah I read that page and I see the option {upload-to} but those options are ' ghosted out'

Comment: Screenshots please. I see no reason at all to sit and guess what else may be wrong.

Comment: How to put screenshots in comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have mappings defined (Settings/Deployment/Mappings)? You won't be able to download/upload anything if mappings are not set or set incorrectly.
Certain actions in Tools | Deployment may also be disabled when no tabs with mapped files were open, so there are no files to upload

Comment: Correct, after i configured the mapping tab the upload function re-appeared under the right mouse button. tnx!